# One way binding between parent and child using Input()

Tags: angular, data-binding

I'm trying to make a modal that shows some data from the parent but I want to only approve that change upon emitting the data upon the confirmation of the form inside the modal, but since I'm using 2 way binding, any change the user might do, would affect the parent even if the user didn't submit the form

So the best solution I came up with is to use one way binding, but I'm unfamiliar how can I do this using Input() since I use it only for 2 way binding

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <app-modal (submitEmitter)="submitted($event)" [dataPassed]="passedData"></app-modal>
</div>




 _dataPassed: Item;
  @Input() set dataPassed(value: Item) {
    if (value) {
      this._dataPassed = value;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() dataPassed: any; // This value can be used anywhere in this class
   @Output() submitEmitter = new EventEmitter<Event>(); //Use this emitter to send data after approval
}
```

Comment: I've added the ts code for the input, it seems that I'm doing this the same way, but it still affects the sent data in the parent

Comment: is that value an object/array? If yes then as a reference value it will update the parent too. If you dont want to mutate then you can clone it whenever you are setting like :
this._dataPassed =  Object.assign({}, value, {}); // or _dataPassed = {...value}